# Getting Checked rows from gridview in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, gridview, checkbox, toggle

I have a `GridView` in ASP.net where I have a `CheckBox` column. The user can toggle the `CheckBox`. Now, what I want is that when the user clicks on a button, all the records from the `GridView` where the `CheckBox` is checked should be displayed. And on another button, the opposite state should be displayed...
I am not getting the logic for the same.

Can anyone please help me with the logic..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could iterate through the `GridViewRow`s and check if the `CheckBox` is checked using something like the following

Edit from comments, fixed small bugs. Thanks guys. (3/20/2013):

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in yourGridViewID.Rows)
{
    CheckBox check = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("CheckBoxName");

    if (check.Checked)
    {
        //Take Row information from each column (Cell) and display it
    }
    else
    {
        //Display in seperate area
    }
}
```

The index is going to be the column number starting from 0, going left to right of which column holds the `CheckBox`. You need to make sure the `CheckBox` has an ID name which is used at CheckBoxName. If you don't have an ID for that, you can also use

```
CheckBox check = (CheckBox)row.Cells[index].Controls[0];
```

Comment: CheckBox check = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("CheckBoxName");  thsi is better to find control from row.

Comment: Yup it works fine :)
One change in the loop as follows.............


foreach (GridViewRow row in yourGridViewID.Rows)
{
    //Copy and paste rest of the stuffs
}

Cheeerz